# Java - Executing commands into a batch file

Tags: java, process, batch-file, command, runtime

I have made a java script which uses the runtime.exec() to execute a batch file, and that works fine but when i get the output stream and use the write() function it does not execute the command i put into it.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p;
p = runtime.exec("cmd /c start batchfile.bat");     
out = p.getOutputStream();
out.write("command".getBytes());
```

It displays the batch file but does not run the command, is there another way of entering a command into the cmd running the batch file so it displays it?

Comment: Are you expecting batchfile.bat to display your command or do you want cmd to do that?

Answer (score 0):

With the start command, a separate command window will be opened, and any output from the batch file will be displayed there. It should also work as just cmd /c build.bat, in which case you can read the output from the subprocess in Java if desired.

Comment: The batch file which calls a jar file creates a log file and to read the output i use that, which works fine and updates when there is new output, all I'm trying to do is send the command to it as you would typing it in to the cmd.

Comment: Hmm not exactly sure what your trying to do, maybe something like ProcessBuilder? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: Im trying to make a minecraft server wrapper http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Programs_and_editors/Server_wrappers im a beginner in java, not sure if im approaching this the right way.

Answer (score -1):

You're writing into an output stream. I think you mean to write to an input stream.

Try this:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p;
p = runtime.exec("cmd /c start batchfile.bat");     
in = p.getInputStream();
in.write("command".getBytes());
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have to write to an output stream, everywhere i looked it was like that. and input stream doesn't have a write function in it anyway.